# How do you store an int or other "C# value types" on the heap (with C#)?

Tags: c#

I'm engaged in educating myself about C# via Troelsen's Pro C# book.

I'm familiar with the stack and heap and how C# stores these sorts of things. In C++, whenever we use `new` we receive a pointer to something on the heap. However, in C# the behavior of `new` seems different to me:

- when used with value types like an int, using `new` seems to merely call the int default constructor yet the value of such an int would still be stored on the stack

I understand that all objects/structs and such are stored on the heap, regardless of whether or not `new` is used.

So my question is: how can I instantiate an `int` on the heap? (And does this have something to do with 'boxing'?)

Comment: 1) why do you want to make an int on the heap? 2) Easiest way I can think of is just make an object with one int in it.

Comment: I know it's a rather "pointless" exercise (pointerless? sic). My question is merely educational.

Comment: From MSDN: "Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or to any interface type implemented by this value type. When the CLR boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a System.Object and stores it on the managed heap."

Comment: @ybakos, BTW in C++ new not necessary allocates anything - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new, so C# behavior of `new` for value types is basically the same as C++ placement new for similar types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can box any value type to `System.Object` type so it will be stored on the managed heap:

```
int number = 1;
object locatedOnTheHeap = number;
```

An other question is why you need this.

This is a classic example from the must-know MSDN paper: [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

> When the CLR boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a
>   System.Object and stores it on the managed heap.
>   Boxing is used to store value types in the garbage-collected heap.
>   Boxing is an implicit conversion of a value type to the type object or
>   to any interface type implemented by this value type. Boxing a value
>   type allocates an object instance on the heap and copies the value
>   into the new object.

.

> I understand that all objects/structs and such are stored on the heap

BTW, IIRC sometimes JIT optimizes code so value type objects like of type like `int` are stored in the CPU registers rather than stack.

Comment: You can also box any value type to `System.ValueType` or to any interface implemented by the type.

Comment: Lots of good answers here; I chose this one b/c it's the most succinct. Thanks sll.

Comment: @sll structs are value type if i'm not wrong, and value types store on stack in memory as int,bool or float. I'm confuse with your statement that all objects/structs are stored on the heap. Will you please elaborate? thanks

Comment: @Ali: The will be stored in heap when boxed into reference `Object` type .

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why you would want to do this, however, in theory you could indeed box your value. You would do this by boxing the int into an object (which is a reference type and will be placed on the stack:

```
object IAmARefSoIWillBeOnHeap = (object)1;
```

*As sll stated, you do not need the `(object)` as it will be an implicit cast. This is here merely for academic reasons, to show what is happening.

[Here is a good article about reference versus value types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx), which is the difference of the heap versus the stack

Comment: @sll Agreed, however I was trying to show the process. I will make a note about that :)

Comment: I know it's a rather "pointless" exercise (pointerless? sic). My question is merely educational.

Comment: @ybakos Understandable. I actually have found Jon Skeets book C# In Depth 2nd Edition to be an amazing reference to REALLY understand some of the underlying details of C#. Especially, coming from a C++ background, there is a part that I personally found interesting that he drove home, about how ref really works and how it kind of relates back to double pointers :)....Either way, a great read if you want to get a deep knowledge...but it is somewhat academic also...and in parts can be somewhat dense material

Comment: Can't this be even more succinct with `object o = 4` ? (per phoog's answer below)

Comment: @ybakos Correct, that is why I added my *, to point out that the cast is merely for academic reasons, and it is not needed as it will be implicitly cast

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean Justin. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

> yet the value of such an int would still be stored on the stack

This is not necessarily true.  Even when it is true, it's purely an implementation detail, and not part of the specification of the language.  The main issue is that the type system does not necessarily correlate to the storage mechanism used by the runtime.

There are many cases where calling new on a struct will still result in an object that isn't on the stack.  Boxing is a good example - when you box an object, you're basically pushing it into an object (effectively "copying" it to the heap), and referencing the object.  Also, any time you're closing over a value type with a lambda, you'll end up "allocating on the heap."

That being said, I wouldn't focus on this at all - the issue really shouldn't about stack vs. heap in allocations, but rather about value type vs. reference type semantics and usage.  As such, I'd strongly recommend reading Eric Lippert's [The Truth About Value Types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx) and Jon Skeet's [References and Values](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html).  Both of these articles focus on the important aspects of struct vs. class semantics instead of necessarily looking at the storage.

As for ways to force the storage of an int on the heap, here are a couple of simple ones:

```
object one = 1; // Boxing
int two = 2; // Gets closed over, so ends up "on the heap"

Action closeOverTwo = () => { Console.WriteLine(two); }
// Do stuff with two here...

var three = new { Three = 3 }; // Wrap in a value type...
```

Comment: Thanks Reed, I've read those and I'm familiar. I just hadn't yet seen a mechanism for storing a value type on the heap, nor did I understand  the nature of "boxing." Now... I do!

Comment: @ybakos Eric's article, in particular, lists many ways that value types get heap storage in Microsoft's CLR implementation.  The main issue he brings up (and I think is the main issue) is that the question itself is faulty, and makes an assumption that storage and type are directly correlated.

Answer (score 2):

A value type is "allocated" wherever it is declared:

- As a local variable, typically on the stack (but to paraphrase Eric Lippert, the stack is an implementation detail, I suggest you read his excellent piece on his blog: [The Truth About Value Types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx).)
- As a field in a class, it expands the size of the instance with the size of the value type, and takes up space inside the instance

As such, this code:

```
var x = new SomeValueType();
```

does *not* allocate something on the heap *by itself* for that value type. If you close over it with an anonymous method or similar, the local variable will be transformed into the field of a class, and  an instance of that class will be allocated on the heap, but in this case, the value type will be embedded into that class as a field.

The heap is for instances of reference types.

However, you've touched up something regarding boxing. You can box a value type value to make a copy of it and place that copy on the heap, wrapped in an object.

So this:

```
object x = new SomeValueType();
```

would first allocate the value type, then box it into an object, and store the reference to that object in `x`.

Comment: " does not allocate something on the heap."  It might - if you close over it, the compiler will rewrite that into a heap allocation ;)

Comment: It'll be a field of a class, but let me clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an int on the heap, you can do this:

```
object o = 4;
```

But basically, you shouldn't want that.  C# is designed for you not to think about such things.  Here's a good place to start on that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is: how can I instantiate an int on the heap? (And does
>   this have something to do with 'boxing'?)

Your understanding about objects and structs are correct.  When you intialized either an object or a structure it goes on the heap.